# Let there be a list of embroidery stitch types

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked a question about an embroidery stitch type. Answer linked to a website where I saw a stitch which was completely new to me.

Since this can have definite answer, should we have a list of types of embroidery stitches on the main site?

I am hoping for name of the stitch with a wiki link to it.

This can community wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that there are a hundred or more embroidery stitches and this would likely need to be an image-heavy list, I strongly recommend that we do **not** do this.

There are sites out there, like the [one I referenced in my answer](http://www.embroidery.rocksea.org/reference/picture-dictionary/), that already do this and I don't know that anyone here will have the time or inclination to make original images for reference... "stealing" (even with permission) all of the images from a site that already does this seems inappropriate for us. Taking one image for reference is one thing. Using a hundred images is too much.

This is something better left to a dedicated site.

Comment: what do you mean by image heavy list? Why would there be any images? I was hoping for name of the stitch with a wiki link to it.

Comment: Having a long list of links to other sites for more information is a pain to maintain (links often die or change). Images are the best way to describe how two embroidery stitches are different.

Comment: Alright, I understand @erica